# Need to know where is the problem with bulk import and how to fix it

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm building an app with Django and I need to import data using django-import-export.

I'm using the bulk import of this last package. I can import the data the first time, but when I try to import it the second time an error occurred. The expected behavior is to not import data and don't cause an error.

My view looks something like this(I simplified the code below since in the actual view I have four resources and four files to import)

```py
def complete_import(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        offering_resource = OfferingResource()
        issuer_resource = IssuerResource()

        offering_dataset = Dataset()
        issuer_dataset = Dataset()

        offering = request.FILES['offering']
        issuer = request.FILES['issuer']

        offering_data = offering_dataset.load(offering.read().decode('utf-8'), format='csv', delimiter='\t', headers=True)
        issuer_data = issuer_dataset.load(issuer.read().decode('utf-8'), format='csv', delimiter='\t', headers=True)
        
        offering_data.append_col(get_quarter, header='quarter')
        issuer_data.append_col(get_quarter, header='quarter')

        offering_result = offering_resource.import_data(offering_data, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)
        issuer_result = issuer_resource.import_data(issuer_data, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)
       
        if not offering_result.has_errors() and issuer_result.has_errors():
            offering_resource.import_data(offering_dataset, dry_run=False)
            del offering_result
            issuer_resource.import_data(issuer_dataset, dry_run=False)
            del issuer_result
        else:
            print('an error occurred')

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

My resource looks like this:

```py
class OfferingResource(ModelResource):
    accession_number = Field(
        attribute='company',
        column_name='ACCESSIONNUMBER',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Company, 'accession_number'))
    quarter = Field(attribute='quarter')
    # other fields
   
    class Meta:
        model = Offering
        use_bulk = True
        skip_diff = True
        batch_size = 1000
        import_id_fields = ('accession_number', 'quarter')

    def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        total_offering_amount = row.get('TOTALOFFERINGAMOUNT')
        try:
            row['TOTALOFFERINGAMOUNT'] = int(total_offering_amount)
        except ValueError:
            row['TOTALOFFERINGAMOUNT'] = -1
        Company.objects.get_or_create(accession_number=row.get('ACCESSIONNUMBER'))


class IssuerResource(ModelResource):
    accession_number = Field(attribute='company',
                            column_name='ACCESSIONNUMBER',
                            widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Company, 'accession_number'))
    quarter = Field(attribute='quarter')
    issuer_seq_key = Field(attribute='issuer_seq_key', column_name='ISSUER_SEQ_KEY')
    # other filds

    class Meta:
        model = Issuer
        use_bulk = True
        skip_diff = True
        batch_size = 1000
        import_id_fields = ('accession_number', 'issuer_seq_key', 'quarter')
```

When I comment the `use_bulk` in the Meta class I get the expected behavior.

#### Edit

The error that I get (I forgot to add it before)

`bulk_update() cannot be used with primary key fields.`

I want to know how can I fix this?

Comment: what errors are you seeing?

Comment: That is the problem,  django-import-export doesn't log or raise the error in the console.

Comment: I suggest run first call with `raise_errors=True`, or step through with debugger

Comment: @MatthewHegarty I used it but in the wrong place, now I corrected this (please check my question). Now I think the problem is caused by the `use_bulk` of the Meta class of resource classes.

Comment: are you getting any error message output?

Comment: @MatthewHegarty I forgot to add it. I re-edited my question to add it (please check my question)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using a primary key field as one of the fields in your Resource list.  You cannot use a primary key field with Django's `bulk_update()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)).

Can you remove the PK field from the list of fields?  If not, is there some other unique field you can use to uniquely identify a record that should be updated.